# how to add values to combobox visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

how do i connect a field from mysql database to my combobox ?
it shows an error .

```
"System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "place" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'"
```

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class OpenNewMishap
    Dim Conns As New Connections()

    Private Sub OpenNewMishap_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        FillCombo()

    End Sub

    Function FillCombo() As String

        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader()
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Place FROM `placesinparameter`", Conns.GetConnection())

        Conns.OpenConnection()

        command.ExecuteReader.Read()
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader("place")))

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The command.ExecuteReader("place") is what is throwing an error.  You could iterate through your results and add them one at a time.  You should look into using a DataAdapter and filling a data object (e.g., DataTable) and then ComboBox1.DataSource = to a DataTable object.

Comment: there is a datatable  ->  table

Answer (score 0):

that works for me:

```
    POTComboBox.DataSource = takala.Getplaces() 
    POTComboBox.ValueMember = "Number"
    POTComboBox.DisplayMember = "place"
```